# Image having .php extension?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I was surfing **[php.net](http://php.net)**

website and seen animated logo but when i have check its extension it was .php file!

It is interesting to see [php](/questions/tagged/php) image file!

The i have downloaded this file http://php.net/images/logo.php

And i am not sure about its document type! So its hard to see its code!

If anybody know how .php extension image works?

Comment: The script generates the raw image and set header, here a png file `Content-Type:image/png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify to treat special file extensions as a specific type in Apache. So for example to set .php as an image you could say:

```
AddType image/jpeg .php
```

in the `mime_module` section of the `httpd.conf` file

Check out:

[PHP Custom File Extensions](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/php-custom-file-extension/)

[MIME-types](http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/gen/Configuring+MIME+Types+in+.htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

The extension doesn't really mean anything, you can have any extension eg `.bob` or no extension.  You could have `.jpg` and return a HTML page, it's the headers' `Content-Type` value that matters.

If you open chrome and load the developer tools, you can see what the header is set to:

[image]

You can see that the type is `image/png` so this is how the browser interprets the output.